# How to uncompress .xml.gz in windows?

Tags: xml, windows, linux, gzip, sitemap

I wrote a script to generate the sitemaps for my website, and then compress the files to .gz. Everything seems to be ok, since google can read the urls from the files. But when I download them by accessing them through the corresponding url in the production enviroment (linux), and then open them with winrar (in my local pc), I get garbage, like it was a binary file or something.

The same thing works fine in my development enviroment (windows), so it seems to be an OS-dependant thing.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried 7-zip or Winzip. Both have support for gz according to their manufacturer websites.