# How to view wget source code?

Tags: wget, gzip

I've gone to this link http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/
and downloaded different versions, but I have no idea how to actually unpack it.

Comment: Download http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/wget-1.13.tar.gz Use something like 7-zip or Winrar to open it.  Look in the `src` folder for the source of the program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484133/whats-a-good-tar-utility-for-windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551338/add-tar-gzip-to-windows-command-line http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261012/how-to-uncompress-xml-gz-in-windows

Comment: No, I know. And i looked, I promise. It felt like an off day to begin with...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to download it. Take a look at [their source code repository](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/wget/trunk/files) and read everything using your browser. Here's [main.c](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/lh/wget/trunk/annotate/head:/src/main.c) for example. More details available at [*How to Access the Wget Source Code Repository*](http://wget.addictivecode.org/RepositoryAccess).

Comment: They've now upgraded to git, apparently: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/wget.git

Answer (score 1):

tar.gz is a common extension for files that have been "tarred" ("tape archive", using the "tar" program), and "gzipped".

Most Linux systems come with these pre-installed, so you can extract the files using something like this:

```
tar xf wget-1.13.tar.gz
```

In Windows, use some unzipper program such as 7-Zip, WinZip, or WinAce or use tar from mingw/cygwin.